# Why is it showing the error parameter is initialized

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

int x=45,y=46,z=65;

if(x>y && x>z)

{

    printf (" i presume %d is greater \n",x);

}

else if(y>z)
 
{

     printf ("actually %d is greater\n",y);

 }
 
else

 {

     printf ("NO,%d is Greater\n",z);

 }
 return 3;
```

Comment: You need an opening `{` between `int main()` and `int x=...` and a closing `}` after the `return` statement.

Comment: I'm new to programming and c is my first language

Comment: @RohitSingh you probably shouldn't learn C as your first language

Comment: @RohitSingh: C is not a good first language for learning how to program - it's probably one of the *worst* first languages for learning how to program.  You're better off starting with something like Python.  It's considerably more straightforward easier to work with when getting started.

Comment: thanks alot for helping me

Comment: Ignore the peanut gallery. C is an okay language for learning programming. A more important factor than which language you learn first is the quality of the textbook you learn from. And it should be a good academic-quality textbook.

Comment: can you please recommend me any textbook  for better understanding

Answer (score 2):

You forgot two braces

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    int x=45,y=46,z=65;

    if(x>y && x>z)

    {

        printf (" i presume %d is greater \n",x);

    }

    else if(y>z)
 
    {

         printf ("actually %d is greater\n",y);

     }
 
     else

     {

         printf ("NO,%d is Greater\n",z);

     }
     return 3;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean braces?

Comment: Oh yeah... my bad

Comment: thank you for the help, ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Because you forgot the braces. It thinks you're trying to create a function in the line that's getting an error. Here's the fixed code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int x = 45, y = 46, z = 65;

if(x>y && x>z)

{

    printf (" i presume %d is greater \n",x);

}

else if(y>z)
 
{

     printf ("actually %d is greater\n",y);

 }
 
else

 {

     printf ("NO,%d is Greater\n",z);

 }
 return 3;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help, ^_^